# Can't Increment and Decrement so well in C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this problem of incrementing and decrementing this code. So to explain this, I have a `.ascx.cs` code where it handles the `UserControl` in `ascx`. and I have a library class converted to `DLL`. so this thing will be used in my DNN portal.

```
public void doIncrement(string propertyKey, UserInfo userInformation, int portalID)
{
    int newDownloadCount = 0;
    int result = 0;
    if ( Int32.TryParse( GetProfilePropertyValue (propertyKey, userInformation), out newDownloadCount))
    {
        int incremented = newDownloadCount += 1;
        userInformation.Profile.SetProfileProperty (propertyKey, incremented.ToString());
        UserController.UpdateUser(portalID, userInformation);
    }
    if (newDownloadCount <= 0)
    {
        int inc = result += 1;
        userInformation.Profile.SetProfileProperty (propertyKey, inc.ToString());
        UserController.UpdateUser(portalID, userInformation);
        throw new Exception ("INVALID");    
    }
}
```

And here's how I manipulate it on the  `ascx.cs`:

```
protected void decrement (object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
     DownloadCtrLib dctrl = new DownloadCtrLib ();
     try
     { 
         dctrl.doDecrement("DownloadLimit", UserInfo, PortalId);
         displayProperty("DownloadLimit", UserInfo);
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         Response.Write (ex.Message);
     }
}
```

Here is my decrement in My dll:

```
    public void doDecrement(string propertyKey, UserInfo userInformation, int portalID)
    {
        int newDownloadCount = 0;
        int result = 0;
        if (int.TryParse (GetProfilePropertyValue (propertyKey, userInformation), out newDownloadCount)) {
            int decremented = newDownloadCount - 1;
            userInformation.Profile.SetProfileProperty (propertyKey, decremented.ToString ());
            UserController.UpdateUser (portalID, userInformation);


        }   
        if (newDownloadCount <= 0) {
            userInformation.Profile.SetProfileProperty (propertyKey, result.ToString ());
            UserController.UpdateUser (portalID, userInformation);
            throw new Exception ("Cannot decrement, number will be negative");  


        }
    }
```

And the manipulation of that doDecrement in ascx is as the same logic with the increment one.. I just want to fix this: I also have a textbox where I can enter the number that will be posted in the label and then decremented or incremented. And the problem is when I enter negative values or null, the label value was still there which I want to refresh as zero and clear the textbox.

And here is my command for the Submit button for entering values in the textbox.

```
uint newDownloadCount = 0;
        int result = 0;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty (txtNewVale) && uint.TryParse (txtNewVale, out newDownloadCount)) {

            userInformation.Profile.SetProfileProperty (propertyKey, newDownloadCount.ToString ());

            UserController.UpdateUser (portalID, userInformation);
        }
        if (newDownloadCount < 0) {
            userInformation.Profile.SetProfileProperty (propertyKey, result.ToString ());
            UserController.UpdateUser (portalID, userInformation);
            txtNewVale = String.Empty();
            throw new Exception ("Cannot decrement, numbers will be negative");
```

Comment: can you explain a little better?

Comment: You only show the code for `doIncrement`, not `doDecrement`, but if you also have something like `if (newDownloadCount <= 0)` .. then `+1` then you force it to 1 after it becomes zero.

Comment: I have edited it already sensei @steve16351 and sir John Stevens.. what do you mean by +1? can you explain further, I must be burned out already by just doing this simple project.

Comment: Where does your propertyKey in .ascx came from? a static class? a session? do you have any FURTHER debug results to find out why nulls or negative values are not passing through the "if (newDownloadCount < 0)" ?

Comment: well sir @ken lacoste, my propertyKey came from my DLL and its a string (it is the representation of my  label value) since I cannot call a user control in my DLL, I use it as an argument, and in my .ascx I call those arguments which I also put in my methods in .ascx.

Comment: the decrement and increment is now working fine, and my problem today is that, my UpdateProperty button for submitting the value to be decremented or incremented which will be place in the label is not returning 0 value when I enter negative value. I just want it to refresh and return 0 value in my label when I entered negative value in the textbox or when the textbox has no value but I still hit the button.. please help :(

Comment: and for the record.. It was all working fine when everything was still on the ascx.. I coded everything there.. but when I migrated some codes in the library class and use the dll as reference, It went like that.. Im not getting the same result.. my boss told me to use SRP(single responsibility principle which I used by promoting codes in library class).